# PhD Email and Deadlines in the US

Tags: phd, email, deadlines

I was considering writing Emails to professors in US universities regarding PhD opportunities at their departments, however I noticed there is a formal PhD application with deadlines in December to follow. So what is the point in contacting professors for placements in their team when there is already an application process similar to undergraduate programmes? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In many departments, when it comes to accepting students, it's good to have a professor put their hand up and say that they would want to work with you and put you on their funding. By the time it gets to accepting students, because there are so many good applicants, the pool has become mostly indistinguishable. Having someone advocating for you at these meetings can make all the difference in the world.

Comment: Note that this is largely field and school dependent. From what I've heard, everything from having previously contacted a specific professor who will vouch for you being a soft requirement to actively discouraging contacting professors beforehand is represented.

Comment: Agreed, thus "in many departments".

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my specialty is Electrical Engineering and Computer Science. If available, is there a list of known US universities who have all year long open applications for PhD?

Comment: @Omar The vast majority of PhD candidates apply during the standard cycle (apply around December/January, start school around August/September). I know that a few programs do off-cycle admissions, but it's very rare, often doesn't come with funding, and makes course scheduling difficult. You almost certainly want to go with the regular admissions cycle.

Comment: @RogerFan, for the record, I applied in August-ish and was admitted for the following January since I was a December graduate (UT-Austin in both cases). There are plenty of schools that do summer applications for spring admits, but I don't know of any that do open admissions.

Comment: @BillBarth Interesting. I knew that some schools did offer off-cycle admissions, but I don't think I've ever met someone who's actually used them. Is that a regular thing at UT-Austin are were you an anomaly? Was course scheduling or funding affected?

Comment: @RogerFan, I dunno. There might have been one more admit that spring in my department (ASE, smallish). I had already taken 1 grad course as finishing undergrad for which I reserved credit (Comp. Grids w/ my PhD super.), and I think I just jumped into mostly non-required courses until I caught up with the usual required sequence. My GRA was fully-funded by my boss's grants, so funding wasn't in question and wasn't from the department. I think I ended up with a small college-level fellowship the following fall that supplemented that. It's been since January '98, so my recollection is hazy.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it depends on the type of school that you want to go to. If you are attending a physical school in person they tend to follow the traditional schedule and have deadlines. However, online universities (of which there are many), often have less stringent application deadlines, or they accept applications all year long.